# getting all data fron joined tables exists and non exists

Tags: mysql, sql

Records from Joined Tables, exists and non exists

table article;

```
+------------+-------+--------+-
| id| cat-id |aut-id |content |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 1 |   1    |    3  |eeeeeee |
| 2 |   2    |    4  |fffffff |
| 3 |   8    |    5  |ggggggg |
| 4 |   9    |    2  |jjjjjjj |
+------------+-------+--------+
```

table categories;

```
+--------------+
| id| cat-name |
+--------------+
| 1 |   phy    |
| 2 |   che    | 
| 3 |   bio    |
+--------------+
```

table authors;

```
+--------------+
| id| aut-name |
+--------------+
| 4 |   joe    |
| 5 |   sam    | 
| 6 |   kim    |
+--------------+
```

I want this result

```
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| id| cat-id |aut-id |cat-name|aut-name|content |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1 |   1    |    3  |  phy   |unknown |eeeeeee |
| 2 |   2    |    4  |  che   |  joe   |fffffff |
| 3 |   8    |    5  |  uncat |  sam   |ggggggg |
| 4 |   9    |    2  |  uncat | unknown|jjjjjjj |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Tried anything yet ? if not then first look at joins in sql

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just LEFT JOIN the data so you wont filter out the missing data

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`, 
    a.`cat-id` , 
    a.`aut-id` , 
    COALESCE(c.`cat-name`, 'uncat') as 'cat-name',
    COALESCE(a1.`aut-name`, 'unknown') as 'aut-name' ,
    a.`content` 
FROM `article` a
LEFT JOIN `categories` c on c.`id` = a.`cat-id`
LEFT JOIN `authors` a1 on a1.`id` = a.`aut-id`
```

use COALESCE to handle null values and put in your desired result

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1e12/3)

## OUTPUT:

```
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| id| cat-id |aut-id |cat-name|aut-name|content |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1 |   1    |    3  |  phy   |unknown |eeeeeee |
| 2 |   2    |    4  |  che   |  joe   |fffffff |
| 3 |   8    |    5  |  uncat |  sam   |ggggggg |
| 4 |   9    |    2  |  uncat | unknown|jjjjjjj |
+------------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: @SaraArif no problem! good luck with your programming endeavors! :)